# Is it possible to inspect the contents of a closure passed as a parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, llvm

Working with Xcode 13.2.1 and Swift 5.X

I have a problem with a function that receives a closure as parameter.   The code has been working fine and now that I implemented new code calling the same function with a different closure (from a different point), when it is executed, it does not do anything (as if the closure is empty).   So I want to debug or inspect what is inside the received closure, but I can't find a way to do it.

I added a simplified example to show what I want to accomplish

```
var closureA = {
    // code here
    print("Closure A")
}

var closureB = {
    // code here
    print("Closure B")
}

func callWithClosure(closure: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    // code
    print("Closure being passed: \(String(describing: closure))")
    closure.debugDescription
    closure?()
}

callWithClosure(closure: closureA)
```

The printout is:

```
Closure being passed: Optional((Function))
Closure A
```

If I add a breakpoint and try to use `po closure` I also only see `Optional(Function)`

Is this a limitation of the LLVM or Xcode?

....e

Comment: There is nothing more for LLVM to print because the compiled code has no traces of the original source left in it; i.e., you can't print a function in Swift and expect to see its source because the source code is irrevocably gone. However, since you are debugging, what happens when you try to _Step In_ to the `closure()` call inside of `callWithClosure()`? Where does it lead you?

Comment: Better yet: can you reduce this problem into a minimal reproducible example that you can share here on SO so someone can help directly explain what might be going on?

Comment: Your example illustrates what you're trying to do, but it doesn't demonstrate the actual problem that you describe, where nothing happens. I guess that's a separate question from what you're asking here, which is just about how to look at a given closure, but if you can update your code so that it a) compiles, and b) shows the root problem, perhaps we can give you a hand with that. Consider asking it as a separate question.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I'm not quite sure what you mean by "there are no traces of the original source left." There are still traces in the debug information, otherwise stepping into a closure wouldn't work. I'm also not aware of any way to *get* to that information in LLDB, but at least file+line information should exist when compiled for debugging.

Comment: My question is about being able to inspect the contents of the closure with 'print' or 'po' as illustrated by the example Playground code..... The context added with a specific problem is to illustrate why I decided to write the sample code.....      it will be hard to try to replicate the problematic code here and it could also be beyond the scope of the question.....     I updated the code for any typo preventing it from running.....      I understand that the source code is gone after compiling, but I was expecting some reference.......     And I still don't understand the downvote...

Comment: @RobNapier Yeah, perhaps better phrased: the source code is not included directly in the compiled binary. As you note, if you compile with debug information, there will be enough information in the executable to point you to key locations _if you have access to the source code_, but you cannot `print()` a closure in Swift and get anything meaningful out. Theoretically, LLDB _could_ override the default description for closures, but the default behavior defers to what is possible at runtime in Swift.

Comment: What were you expecting to be able to see, if not `Optional((Function))`?  The hex bytes for the function?

Answer (score 2):

> So I want to debug or inspect what is inside the received closure, but I can't find a way to do it.

There's no way to print the source code of an arbitrary closure from inside your program.

That said, you *can* use the debugger to see the code. Set a breakpoint on the `closure()` call or in the closure you're interested in and debug the program. Execution will stop at the breakpoint, just as with any other code, and you can step through the closure's code. You can also look at the stack trace to see how you reached that point in the code, and you can inspect the calling code to see what closure is being passed in.

> If I add a breakpoint and try to use po closure I also only see Optional(Function)

Debugging into a closure works because the debugger knows how to connect the object code to the source code that it was compiled from. But at run time, all the source code has already been compiled -- the contents of the closure itself is object code, not source code that you can inspect. It's a limitation neither of Xcode nor of LLVM -- it's just how software works in a compiled environment.

Comment: I corrected the code for any typo preventing it from running.. Pls see my comment in the question thread....

Comment: @eharo2 I've updated my answer a bit. Even so, this feels like an XY problem -- you're trying to print the code in a closure, but the real problem is that the closure doesn't seem to do anything. Why isn't the debugger sufficient for solving that?